# Data display on table from two API endpoint ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, api

I have mentioned the code below guys please help me solve this problem.

I have three columns Company Name address and user
Compnay Name Address is coming from one API endpoint and user_id shall be extracted from the first data and send it to another endpoint and get the information of the user i.e. username and show it on the same table under users column.

```js
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import SideDrawer from '../components/SideDrawer/SideDrawer'
import Table from '../components/table/Table';
import './Companies.scss';
import Filter from '../components/FIlter/Filter';
import Freeze from '../icons/Freeze.svg'
import Button from '../components/button/Button';
import exportIcon from '../icons/export.svg';

const dropDownData = [
    {itemName: "Setting", link:'#'},
    {itemName: "Close", link:'#'},
]
function Companies() {
    const [datas, setDatas] = useState([])
    const [user, setUser] = useState([])
    const [userID, setUserID] = useState('')
    const [username, setUserName] = useState('')
    const authToken = process.env.AUTH_TOKEN
    console.log(authToken)
    useEffect(() => {
        fetch("",{
            method: "GET",
            headers:{
                authorization: "Bearer <TOKEN>"
            }
        })
          .then(res => res.json())
          .then(tableData => {
            setDatas(tableData);
            console.log(tableData)
            tableData.map(data=>data.users.map(data => (fetchUserData(data.user_id))))
          })
      }, [userID])
    //   console.log(userID)
    function fetchUserData(userID) {
        // console.log(userID)
        fetch(`https://api/accounts/users/getUser?user_id=${userID}`,{
                method: "GET",
                headers:{
                    authorization: "Bearer <TOKEN>"
                }
            })
            .then(res=> res.json())
            .then(users => {
                // console.log(users.username)
                setUserName(users.username)
            })
    }
      function renderBody() {
          console.log(datas.users)
        return (
          <tbody>
              {datas.map(data => (
                <tr>
                    <td key={data.company_name}>{data.company_name}</td>
                    <td key={data._id}>{data.address}</td>
                    <td key={username}>{username}</td>
                </tr>
              ))}
          </tbody>
        );
      }    
    return (
        <div className="companies">
            <SideDrawer activeLink={'/companies'}/>
            <div className="companies__content">
            <h1>Companies</h1>
            <div className="companies__menu">
                <div className="companies__menu_left">
                    <Filter data={dropDownData}/>
                </div>
                
                <div className="companies__menu_right">
                    <Button buttonLabel="Export" type="textButton" icon={exportIcon}/>
                    <Button buttonLabel="Freeze" type="textButton" icon={Freeze}/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="companies_table">
                        <table>
                            
                            <tr>
                                <th>Company Name</th>
                                <th>Address</th>
                                <th>Users</th>
                            </tr>
                            {renderBody()}
                        </table>
                        </div>
            
            </div>
            
        </div>
    )
}

export default Companies
```

Comment: Hi Rabin, can you please detail your question and what you are struggling with ?

Answer (score 0):

Just merge the fields on fetchUserData:

Pass the DataIndex from your tableData map and then update that record.

Comment: Sir, I mistakenly shared the API endpoint can you please help me by removing the link.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import SideDrawer from '../components/SideDrawer/SideDrawer'
import Table from '../components/table/Table';
import './Companies.scss';
import Filter from '../components/FIlter/Filter';
import Freeze from '../icons/Freeze.svg'
import Button from '../components/button/Button';
import exportIcon from '../icons/export.svg';

const dropDownData = [
    { itemName: "Setting", link: '#' },
    { itemName: "Close", link: '#' },
]
function Companies() {
    const [datas, setDatas] = useState([])
    const [user, setUser] = useState([])
    const [userID, setUserID] = useState('')
    const [usernames, setUserNames] = useState({})
    const authToken = process.env.AUTH_TOKEN
    console.log(authToken)
    useEffect(() => {
        getOrg();
    }, [userID])
    //   console.log(userID)

    const getOrg = () => {
        let users = {};
        return fetch("https://example.com/accounts/getOrg", {
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                authorization: "Bearer <TOKEN>"
            }
        })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(tableData => {
                setDatas(tableData);
                console.log(tableData)
                tableData.fpr(data => data.users.map(({ user_id }) => {
                    users[user_id] = true; // remove duplicate call
                }))
                Object.keys(users).map(fetchUserData); // Can use Promise.all
            })
    }
    const fetchUserData = async (userID) => {
        const users = await fetch(`https://example.com/accounts/users/getUser?user_id=${userID}`, {
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                authorization: "Bearer <TOKEN>"
            }
        }).then(res => res.json());

        setUserNames({
            ...usernames,
            userID: users
        })
    }
    function renderBody() {
        console.log(datas.users)
        return (
            <tbody>
                {datas.map(data => (
                    <tr>
                        <td key={data.company_name}>{data.company_name}</td>
                        <td key={data._id}>{data.address}</td>
                        <td key={usernames[data.user_id]}>{usernames[data.user_id]}</td> //get print whatever is required
                    </tr>
                ))}
            </tbody>
        );
    }
    return (
        <div className="companies">
            <SideDrawer activeLink={'/companies'} />
            <div className="companies__content">
                <h1>Companies</h1>
                <div className="companies__menu">
                    <div className="companies__menu_left">
                        <Filter data={dropDownData} />
                    </div>

                    <div className="companies__menu_right">
                        <Button buttonLabel="Export" type="textButton" icon={exportIcon} />
                        <Button buttonLabel="Freeze" type="textButton" icon={Freeze} />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="companies_table">
                    <table>

                        <tr>
                            <th>Company Name</th>
                            <th>Address</th>
                            <th>Users</th>
                        </tr>
                        {renderBody()}
                    </table>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
    )
}

export default Companies
```

Comment: Sir, I mistakenly shared the API endpoint can you please help me by removing the link.